# Node Scraper using request module returning undefined for response

Tags: jquery, node.js, cheerio, scraper

I am trying to run a nodejs scraper , using request module. Following is the js code

```js
var request = require('request')
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
urls =[];

request({uri:'https://www.bloomingdales.com'},
function(err,resp,body){
    console.log(body);
    if(!err && resp.statusCode == 200){
        var $ = cheerio.load(body);
    }
    else
        console.log(err);
})
```

when i do console.log(body)..I am getting undefined..however when url is changed to www.flipkart.com or any other i get html on response.
I get the warning saying

> (node:9828) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11
>   pipe listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase lim it

getting the following error

> Error: Exceeded maxRedirects. Probably stuck in a redirect loop
>   https://www.bloomingdales.com/
>       at Redirect.onResponse (C:\Users\SanjanaHE\Desktop\Scraper\node_modules\request\lib\redirect.js:98:27)
>       at Request.onRequestResponse (C:\Users\SanjanaHE\Desktop\Scraper\node_modules\request\request.js:996:22)
>       at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
>       at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
>       at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:473:21)
>       at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:99:23)
>       at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:362:20)
>       at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
>       at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
>       at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)

How to resolve this

Comment: First, check if `err` is null. If it is not, you have errors, and your body will be undefined. Put your `console.log` in your if, and add an `else` bloc code where you output the error.

Comment: @Seblor I have edited code with else statement which is giving error as above

Comment: Weird. Might be some trick made by the server depending on the headers (like with the user-agent) to prevent basic scrapping. (or just a server misconfiguration)

Comment: anyway to overcome this?

Comment: I was looking at it, the server is returning a 302 error "moved temporarily". I don't know why or how to move around it. Only solution I have in mind would be to use a headless browser (you're lucky, Google published its own a few days ago : Puppeteer which looks really easy to use).